# Multicasting Observable value to many subscribers

Tags: rx-java

Let's assume that I have a function like this

```
public Observable<Data> getData() {
    return Observable.concat(cacheObservable(), networkObservable()).first();
}
```

It's returning Observable with data from the cache or network. If value is already saved cacheObservable will return it otherwise network call is made.

I'm wondering how I could handle given scenario:

1) Subscriber subscribes to getData observable.

2) Cache is empty so networkObservable will be used.

3) During network request second subscriber is subscribing to getData observable and another request is made(since cache is still empty)

How can I assure that second subscriber will reuse value from the first request and request will be only made for the 1st subscription?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Observable.share()` for multicasting - late subscribers will get same stream as soon as there is 1 subsriber, but this will work only if late subscribers subscribe before upstream is not finished yet (and they will lose already emitted items). If you have all subscribers in advance, then there is also `Observable.publish()`, which returns `ConnectableObservable` - one needs to call its `connect()` to trigger subscription

```
public Observable<Data> getData() {
   return Observable.concat(cacheObservable(), networkObservable()).first().share();
}
```